# How to build a Tizen TV app with "Autorun Last App" function. TV Model 2021

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I developed a Web APP for Samsung TVs (for 2021 models). But I can't find a solution to autorun my app if it was opened before power off and the TV is powered on again. **Instead a default app is opened**.
The "Autorun Last App"-setting is active and this function works well for other APPs like YouTube and Amazon Prime Video.

At least the app is not completely shut down on power off. The state of the app is stored in background/RAM if I power off the TV or switch to other app. Then it can be resumed to last state - even after power on.

What is missing for autorun after power on?

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="https://www.herber-edevelopment.de/Example" version="1.0.3" viewmodes="fullscreen">
    <tizen:app-control>
        <tizen:src name="index.html" reload="disable"/>
        <tizen:operation name="http://samsung.com/appcontrol/operation/eden_resume"/>
        <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/productinfo"/>
    </tizen:app-control>
    <tizen:application id="xxx" package="xxx" required_version="2.3"/>
    <author href="https://www.herber-edevelopment.de/" email="...">Jaroslav Herber</author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <description xml:lang="de">...</description>
    <description>...</description>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.1080.1920"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="app-icon3.png"/>
    <name>Example</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/display"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.info"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/download"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.write"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
    <tizen:profile name="tv-samsung"/>
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape" context-menu="disable" background-support="enable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung SmartTV were grouped.

Autorun last app is related with multitasking functionality
Your config.xml is right.
But Some TV group doesn't support multitasking.
I think your TV doesn't support it.
Amazon and Youtube are special purpose app. So we don't apply these app multitasking option.

If you see following site, you can find multitasking support group.

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/fundamentals/multitasking.html

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm this theory. Autorun last app works on GQ65QN94AAT - but not on GU32T5379